# How to enable my python code to read from Arabic content in Excel?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I have two related problems. I'm working on Arabic dataset using Excel. I think that Excel somehow reads the contents as ؟؟؟؟؟ , because when I tried to replace this character '؟' with this '?' it replaces the whole text in the sheet. But when I replace or search for another letter it works.

Second, I'm trying to edit the sheet using python, but I'm unable to write Arabic letters (I'm using jGRASP). For example when I write the letter 'ل' it appears as 0644, and when I run the code this message appears : "ُError encoding text. Unable to encode text using charset windows-1252 ".

Comment: Make sure the sheet that you are trying to write using python has a UTF-8 / 16/ 32 encoding, and so does your file object in python. Because as the error suggests, windows OS uses windows-1252 encoding by default which is a 8 bit encoding system, like latin 1. And it does not support Arabic character set, so that may possibly be one of the reason for your error.

Answer (score 0):

0644 is the character code of the character in hex. jGRASP displays that when the font does not contain the character. You can use "Settings" > "Font" in jGRASP to choose a CSD font that contains the characters you need. Finding one that has those characters and also works well as a coding font might not be possible, so you may need to switch between two fonts.

jGRASP uses the system character encoding for loading and saving files by default. Windows-1252 is an 8-bit encoding used on English language Windows systems. You can use "File" > "Save As" to save the file with the same name but a different encoding (charset). Once you do that, jGRASP will remember it (per file) and you can load and save normally. Alternately, you can use "Settings" > "CSD Windows Settings" > "Workspace" and change the "Default Charset" setting to make the default something other than the system default.